# Very new to Javascript. How can I make this code extendable/cleaner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a webapp that I am developing I need to populate table columns with data that changes dependent on a dropdown select menu. I have a solution below, which works fine and all, but as I only really started learning javascript/JQuery this morning I am sure it isn't a very good one. When I start to work with larger tables or with lots of dropdown fields it's going to get messy. Is there any way I can do this better?

Thanks,

Mark

```
var GBP = new Array();
GBP[0] = "£1";
GBP[1] = "£2";
GBP[2] = "£3";
GBP[3] = "£4";
GBP[4] = "£5";
GBP[5] = "£6";
GBP[6] = "£7";

var EUR = new Array();
EUR[0] = "€1";
EUR[1] = "€2";
EUR[2] = "€3";
EUR[3] = "€4";
EUR[4] = "€5";
EUR[5] = "€6";
EUR[6] = "€7";

var USD = new Array();
USD[0] = "$1";
USD[1] = "$2";
USD[2] = "$3";
USD[3] = "$4";
USD[4] = "$5";
USD[5] = "$6";
USD[6] = "$7";

$(document).ready(function() {

    //populate currency column with default values (GBP)
    $('#prices tr').each(function(i) {
            $(this).find('.currency').html(GBP[i]);
    });

    //populate the currency column with a value dependent
    //on the selector dropdown 
    $('.currency-select').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "GBP"){
            $('#prices tr').each(function(i) {
                $(this).find('.currency').html(GBP[i]);
            }); 
        }

        if($(this).val() == "EUR"){
            $('#prices tr').each(function(i) {
                $(this).find('.currency').html(EUR[i]);
            });
        }

        if($(this).val() == "USD"){
            $('#prices tr').each(function(i) {
                $(this).find('.currency').html(USD[i]);
            });
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: More suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ah. Thank you Ant P. I was not aware of codereview.stackexchange.com. This would indeed be better suited there.

Comment: I would like to point out that if you are just learning JavaScript, you should absolutely not be using jQuery. You should learn the basic and infinitely flexible [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) first, and then use jQuery if you truly feel you need it (hint: you don't)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an object. Since the values are getting incremented by `1`, you can use the `index` of the selected elements for generating values dynamically, `html` method like most of the jQuery object's methods accepts a callback function.

The first argument of the callback is the `index` of the selected element in jQuery collection(*selected elements*). The retuned valued of the function will be set as new html content of the element.

```
var cur = {
   GBP: '£',
   EUR: '€',
   USD: '$'
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.currency-select').change(function() {
        // Getting symbol based on the current value
        var c = cur[this.value];
        $('#prices tr').find('.currency').html(function(i) {
            return c + (i+1); 
        }); 
    }).change(); // trigger the change event once on DOM ready
});
```

Edit: In case that values are not incremented by `1`:

```
var cur = {
   GBP: '£',
   EUR: '€',
   USD: '$',
   values: ['3', '4', '0', '9', '...']
}

$('#prices tr').find('.currency').html(function(i) {
    return c + cur.values[i]; 
});
```

[**Demo on jsFiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8J2d/)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for response. Really appreciate the help. Having a little trouble implementing your code. Bit confused as what     function(i) { return c + (i+1);}); is doing. 

Also, the values are just arbitrary ones I chose for the example. In my real tables they will not increment like that.

Comment: @MarkWilliams You are welcome, `c` is the symbol and `i` is the index, 1, 2, 3..., . I have updated the answer, if the vales of all currencies are the same, you can use _an_ array. I have updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Works a charm. Had to modify your code a little to account for different values for different currencies. Thanks for help :)